# Custom Horizontal View Pager to page through ListViews populated from Database Tables

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, android-viewpager

I am Implementing a custom Horizontal View Pager. My Intention is to populate the entries of a particular table in a ListView. The method have to detect how many tables are there in the database and set as many pages for the horizontal view pager. (One Page for One TABLE - Each page contains only one ListView to showing entries of the corresponding TABLE).

Here's my tries.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewp);
    MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
    ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.threepageviewer);
    myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    DbHelper helper = new DbHelper(this);
    count = helper.countTables();
    myPager.setCurrentItem(count);
    temp = helper.countTables() - 1;
    temp1 = helper.countTables() - 1;
}
```

here's the page adapter class.

```
private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View view = null;


        if (position == count-1) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.middle, null);
            ListView list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            helper = new DbHelper(Listing.this);
            String tabName = helper.getTableName(temp1);
            dataset_cursor = helper.getAll(tabName);
            startManagingCursor(dataset_cursor);
            adapter = new NoteAdapter(dataset_cursor);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        if (position < temp) {
            temp--;
            temp1--;
            // int hg = temp - position;
            // int tempo = temp - hg;
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.left, null);
            ListView list1 = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            helper = new DbHelper(Listing.this);
            String tabName = helper.getTableName(temp1);
            dataset_cursor1 = helper.getAll(tabName);
            startManagingCursor(dataset_cursor1);
            adapter1 = new NoteAdapter(dataset_cursor1);
            list1.setAdapter(adapter1);
            adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), tabName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            temp--;
            temp1--;
        }
        if (position > temp) {
            temp++;
            temp1++;
            // int hg = position - temp;
            // int tempo = temp - hg;
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.right, null);
            ListView list2 = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            helper = new DbHelper(Listing.this);
            String tabName = helper.getTableName(temp1);
            dataset_cursor2 = helper.getAll(tabName);
            startManagingCursor(dataset_cursor2);
            adapter2 = new NoteAdapter(dataset_cursor2);
            list2.setAdapter(adapter2);
            adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);
        return view;
    }
```

I want the Last Database Table to be the default page. when I swipe left It should go to the second-last Table and so on. While trying this I almost get what I need. Except this problem .

**END**--**TABLE6**--(left swipe)--**TABLE5**--(left swipe)--**TABLE5**--(left swipe)--**TABLE3**--(left swipe)--**TABLE2**--(left swipe)--**TABLE1**--**END**

**END**--**TABLE1**--(right swipe)--**TABLE2**--(right swipe)--**TABLE2**--(right swipe)--**TABLE3**--(right swipe)--**TABLE4**--(right swipe)--**TABLE5**--**END**

I am doing it correctly. what could be the mistake here. Is there any other way to implement the same ?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you encounter? What are you trying to achieve? It's not clear

Comment: Trying to implement a view pager. I have a database. The view pager should have a number of pages equal to the number of tables in the database. Each page in the View pager has a listview which shows the values in the corresponding table of the database. That's what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I get it know, there's TABLE5 and TABLE2 twice - that is the problem. I just could not get what went wrong, it looked like you achieved it

Comment: But for this problem (TABLE5 and TABLE2 twice) I achieved it.

Comment: what is the use of temp and temp1? Cant you use `position` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because of your `temp` and `temp1` variables. Do the following..

```
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
     ...
     ...
     ListView list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
     helper = new DbHelper(Listing.this);
     String tabName = helper.getTableName(position+1);
     dataset_cursor[position] = helper.getAll(tabName);
     startManagingCursor(dataset_cursor[position]);
     adapter = new NoteAdapter(dataset_cursor[position]);
     list.setAdapter(adapter);
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

     ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

     return view;
}
```

If you want to maintain multiple dataset cursors then have dataset cursor array declared, which can be easily accessed like `dataset_cursor[position]` as shown above.

Comment: I have a doubt regarding View pager. Should there be three layouts (default one , one for left swipe, and one for right) for the view pager to work ?

Comment: I get an error in this line dataset_cursor[position] = helper.getAll(tabName);

Comment: here's my code in the helper.  public Cursor getAll(String tableName) {
  return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id, note type FROM "
    + tableName, null));

 }

Comment: error? what error? have you declared `dataset_cursor` as `new` array of type `Cursor`?

Answer (score 1):

First that looks not good:

```
temp--;
temp1--;
...
temp--;
temp1--;
```

Ok you are using temp variables to compare with you position but the variable do not represent what you want.

1. You decrement to much you variables. I suggest that you remove the second of the too decrements in you code.
2. `if(position < temp)` you decrement you temp twice and compare it again in ? `if(position>temp)` now temp may be smaller -> not what you want.

I Suggest that you use the position directly to get the correct table and use `ELSE IF's`